# Magento 2: Invalid UI Component element name 'product_form'

Tags: magento2, admin, attributes, catalog

I'm getting Unusual error on Admin.

In my local it's working fine. But on server when i try to select my newly created Attribute Set

```
domain.com/admin_ychhtn/catalog/product/reload/type/simple/store/0/popup/1/componentJson/1/prev_set_id/4/key/986e85ebbdfe1560684f97bc8e942e09d9f401ef6e3a87f501a5539ea2a6744d/?set=9&isAjax=true
```

Above AJAX URL Leads to 503 Service Unavailable. So it's not loading my Attributes.

I have checked in error log it says

```
a:4:{i:0;s:49:"Invalid UI Component element name: 'product_form'";i:1;s:3651:"#0 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(144): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepareData('product_form')
#1 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('product_form', NULL, Array)
#2 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'product_form', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#3 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#4 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#5 /var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#6 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#7 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#10 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(217): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#11 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/Amasty/AdminActionsLog/Observer/handleLayoutRenderBefore.php(36): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getTitle()
#12 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73): Amasty\AdminActionsLog\Observer\handleLayoutRenderBefore->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#13 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Amasty\AdminActionsLog\Observer\handleLayoutRenderBefore), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#14 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#15 /var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('layout_render_b...', Array)
#16 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(166): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('layout_render_b...')
#17 /var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#18 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#19 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#20 /var/www/html/magento/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#21 {main}";s:3:"url";s:182:"/admin_ychhtn/catalog/product/reload/type/simple/store/0/popup/1/componentJson/1/prev_set_id/4/key/986e85ebbdfe1560684f97bc8e942e09d9f401ef6e3a87f501a5539ea2a6744d/?set=9&isAjax=true";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

I cleared `var/cache` & `var/generation` folder as well. Still Issue.

`magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Reload.php`

Need to debug on above file How?

When i add Product Attribute is not loading, But when i do Update for Product at that time only it loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue. Disabling the Amasty_AdminActionsLog fixed this for us.

Comment: You are absolutely right. By disabling that Module It Works Fine. Contacting Extension Provider to Solve Issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: how to know which modules files is cause the error.. I also same problem "Invalid UI Component element name: ''

Comment: @SatishVishwakarma Sorry for late reply, don't know if it's relevant anymore. In this case, you can see the Amasty module mentioned at #11 in the error log debug trace. However, if your issue doesn't come from this module, find the error log entry and look for the first line mentioning a non /vendor/ file path, as that will most likely be the custom code causing this error