# Magento 2: How to Set Max Length on Billing Address at Checkout Page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation, customer-address, billing-address

I have achieved for Shipping Address [Magento 2: How to set Max Length for Street Address?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148951/magento-2-how-to-set-max-length-for-street-address)

Struggling with Billing Address on `domain.com/checkout/#payment`

My Payment Method is Bank Transfer. I have tried below code, but seems not working.

**magento\app\code\Custom\Checkout\Block\LayoutProcessor.php**

```
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payments-list']['children']['banktransfer-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['street'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
        'label' => __('Street Address'),
        'required' => true,
        'dataScope' => 'banktransfer-form.street',
        //'displayArea' => 'billing-address-form-banktransfer',
        //'deps' => 'checkoutProvider',
        //'dataScopePrefix' => 'billingAddressbanktransfer',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'sortOrder' => 60,
        'type' => 'group',
        'children' => [
                [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'banktransfer-form',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '0',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 50],
            ],
                [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'banktransfer-form',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                ],
                'dataScope' => '1',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'validation' => ['required-entry' => false, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 50],
            ]
        ]
    ];

//        echo "<pre>";
//        print_r($jsLayout);
//        exit;
```

Comment: Have you try with same as shipping?

Comment: Hi @Rakesh for Shipping Address it's working fine. Only issue with Billing Address

Comment: You can try with,  $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payments-list']['children']['banktransfer']['children']['form-fields']['children']['street'],  banktransfer-form with banktransfer only.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh have replaced `banktransfer-form` with `banktransfer` in whole file. Seems not working & Giving Error

Comment: please share your error code for above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have issue regarding not getting form-fields,

So you have to just keep below code in your plugin file using if condition,

```
if ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']) {
    foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
        ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $value
    ) {
        if($value['component'] == 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address') {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
['payments-list']['children']['banktransfer-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['street'] = [ 'your customization' ]
        }
    }
}
```

Where **your customization** in above code you have to keep your code for override.

Comment: U r Excellent @Rakesh Again. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Min & Max Length Validation works fine. Have small Issue. It applies but strangely. When user on Payment Section & Change his Billing Address & Click on "Update" at that time "Street Address" validation is not executing.When i focus or click on Street Address 1 Field only, that time it's executing. On Shipping Address i'm not facing this issue. Something minor missing. Don't know. In Short It's not Executing Street Address 1 is a Required Field on load.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh Need ur help on this one as well if can http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147704/magento-2-invalid-ui-component-element-name-product-form